# Which meanings of seal verb is applicable here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which one of the "seal" verb meanings is appropriate in the following sentences?

> The researchers noted that the margays’ high-pitched squeals weren’t a
>   very good imitation of a baby tamarin, but that the squealing sound
>   attracted the attention of adult tamarins away. Still, none of the
>   tamarins really **sealed** the trick.

Comment: As a British-English speaker I did not understand the use of 'seal' until I read the answers. Maybe 'sealed the deal' is an American-English idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage 4, from the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/seal):

> Conclude, establish, or secure (something) definitively.

If one was to literally seal a letter using wax, "sealing the letter" would be the final step that concludes the process of writing the letter.

This usage of *seal* is common in phrases such as "seal the deal" or "seal the bargain". In both examples, "sealing the deal/bargain" would mean accomplishing the final step in the negotiation process for the deal/bargain.

In the same way, "sealing the trick" would mean succeeding at the final step of convincingly mimicking a baby tamarin. Since the margays were unable to convince the tamarins, they could not conclude this final step and "seal the trick".

Comment: This is quite common usage in British English - seal a deal, a bargain, a matter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a play on the more common phrase "sealed the deal." The phrase is a reference to bygone times when paperwork would carry a official seal.

So in the quoted sentence "sealed the trick" means that none of the margays convincingly mimicked a baby tamarin.